# Running AWS SAM projects locally get error

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli

I am trying to run an AWS Lambda project locally on Ubuntu. When I run the  project with AWS SAM Local it shows me this error: `Error: Running AWS SAM projects locally requires Docker. Have you got it installed?`

Answer (score 32):

Another cause for this is [this recent issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/4329#issuecomment-1289588827) within Docker for Mac.

A quick workaround, as specified in the issue itself, is to run SAM with:

```bash
$ DOCKER_HOST=unix://$HOME/.docker/run/docker.sock sam local start-api
```

You don't need to run SAM as `root`.

Comment: I have Docker Desktop installed on Linux. This worked with a slight modification, since `docker.sock` lives under `~/.docker/desktop`.

Comment: This worked for me 22/3/23 on a Mac with up-to-date docker installed and available on the CL.

Comment: Docker Desktop -> Go to the Dashboard -> Settings -> Advanced -> **Allow the default Docker socket to be used (requires password)**. No longer need to set `DOCKER_HOST` env var.

Answer (score 15):

I had trouble installing it on Fedora.

When I followed the Docker postinstall instructions I managed to get past this issue.

https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/

I had to:

1. Delete the ~/.docker directory;
2. Create the "docker" group;
3. Add my user to the "docker" group;
4. Logout and back in again;
5. Restart the "docker" daemon.

I was then able to run the command:

```
sam local start-api
```

Comment: In Ubuntu 18 I just needed to add my user in the "docker" group (It was already created) and that was all

Comment: Please do not forget to reboot afterward!

Comment: This is the solution in Ubuntu 22. I think it works because it allows sam to call docker without using sudo.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to run local `sam-cli`, you have first [install docker](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-docker-ce) from docker official website then run `sudo sam local start-api`. Note that sudo is necessary for running local developer with needed privileges.

Comment: running as root worked for me, do you know why this is necessary?

Comment: It should have to do with docker having to be invoked with sudo. I think that as of docker version 19 one can run it sudoless, but there are some caveats. All this is just a guess though.

Answer (score 7):

I am using colima for docker on mac with intel chip. and faced this error. was able to resolve it by adding `DOCKER_HOST` in `.zshrc` file

```
vi ~/.zshrc
```

paste `export DOCKER_HOST="unix://$HOME/.colima/docker.sock"` in the .zshrc file
`escape` :wq

Comment: perhaps `~/.zshenv`

Answer (score 7):

This solved it for me on Mac:

1. Click the settings "cog" icon in the top right
2. Open the "Advanced" section
3. Tick "Allow the default Docker socket to be used"
4. Click the "Apply and restart" button

[image]

Comment: This resolved the issue. It needed to be on top.

Answer (score 4):

This error mostly arises due to lack of admin privilege to use docker. Just add sudo to your command. This will work.
eg: `sudo sam local start-api --region eu-west-3`

Answer (score 2):

We are working on Mac and were seeing same message when using an older version of Docker (1.12.6). Have since updated to a newer (but not latest) version 17.12.0-ce-mac49 and it is now fine.

Comment: Absolutely. Upgrading Docker, Docker Desktop and (in my case) Rider and AWS Toolkit for Rider helped me solve that issue.

Answer (score 1):

For those with Macs and using colima for docker, check two things:

1. ~/.zshrc or ~/.bashrc have DOCKER_HOST pointed to `unix://$HOME/.colima/docker.sock"`, like `export DOCKER_HOST="unix://$HOME/.colima/docker.sock"`
2. Make sure colima is actually running. `colima start`